# Take a joke or prank

Tags: word-usage

The word **joke** is used in the following idiom:

**Take a joke** which means "to laugh when someone says something funny about you and not be offended"

> I think we can use "prank" in a similar way, as both of these are synonyms.

I want to use it specifically in the following sentence:

> My friend has a very bad habit. He used to play pranks on others; but at the same time, he is not willing to **take the same prank** on himself.

If I rephrase it as follows, will it be correct:

> My friend has a very bad habit. He used to play pranks on others; but at the same time, he is not ready **to be the victim of similar pranks**.

Comment: Sure, you *can* use that, and some people might recognize what you're doing with it, but then again they might not, meaning it might be an awkward turn of phrase for them. Use at your discretion.

Comment: It's not really the idiomatic expression.  Someone who is okay when pranks are played on him is called a "good sport".   Otherwise we would say that he "can't take a **joke**".

Comment: @Andrew So we can phrase the sentence as follows: My friend has a very bad habit. He used to play pranks on others; but at the same time, he is not willing to take the same jokes on himself.

Comment: You could say something more like "He can't take having the prank pulled on him". This is a common way of using "take" that doesn't have the same idiomatic need as "take a joke".

Comment: I think part of this stems from your incorrect use of "take a joke" in your first sentence, though... I don't think we'd say "He is not willing to take a joke on himself." That doesn't really work for me. You'd need to say "He can't take a joke"... that's how we use it in the negative most often.

Comment: @abhijeetpathak  What Catija said.  It's not an expression you can freely conjugate.  One possible phrase is to **pull** a prank -- your friend likes to prank other people, but doesn't like having the same pranks *pulled* on him.